# Getting invalid csrf token

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am playing around with node and mongo. I currently have a simple website. The website was working up until I implemented the csurf module. I am following a tutorial on it but cant seem to know why its not working.

This is my user route (user.js) which is the only place where I require csurf:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf');
var passport = require('passport');

var csrfProtection = csrf();
router.use(csrfProtection);

router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile');
});

router.post('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {

    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});


router.use('/', notLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
    next();
});

//GETS THE SIGNUP view
router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('signup', {
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
    });
});

router.get('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('signin', {
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
    });
});

//HAPPENS WHEN THE USER CLICKS SUBMIT POST
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
    successRedirect: '/user/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/user/signup',
    failureFlash: true

}));

router.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local.signin', {
    successRedirect: '/user/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/user/signin',
    failureFlash: true

}));




module.exports = router;

//Used for declaring if user is logged and and authenticated
//.isAuthenticated is from passport and is automatically created when user
//is logged on
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }

}


function notLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }

}
```

This is the error log:

```
    ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
at csrf (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\csurf\index.js:112:19)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
at C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
at router (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
at C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\app.js:48:5
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\RyanCarruthers\Desktop\shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
```

This is my app.js file. Commented out certain things e.g. sessions to play around with them.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var user = require('./routes/users');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

//var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var app = express();


mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/shopping');
require('./config/passport');;
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(session({
     secret: 'mysupersecret',
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: false
 }));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Is called EVERYTIME a rquest is made
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    //res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});

app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/', routes);





module.exports = app;
```

EDIT = Okay so i managed to fix my misconfigured csurg. The problem was got to do with the session it was trying to use. I edited the session (im using express-session module) and now its working.  BUT i do have a logout button in which I am sending a POST HTTP method to '/user/profile' in which the user should log out. I am getting a 403 error and dont know why.

Comment: Any way you could pare down this code and still make the issue reproducible? Seems like there is a fair amount here that is unnecessary.

Comment: @LarryTurtis well the issue the error log says line 49 at the app.js file, which is where my .isAuthenticated() method is called. Might this be a problem conflicting with passport plugin?

Comment: Possibly. I'm just saying remove all the unecessary routes and includes... get this down to the bare minimum you need for the issue to be reproducible.

Comment: @LarryTurtis I fixed my issue and got rid of a bit of unecessary code in the app.js file. I have updated my question to reflect the new issue